# Programatically updating SharePoint custom field type column value 

Tags: sharepoint, custom-fields, custom-field-type

I have created a custom field type (say 'Sample') in SharePoint which is based on 'multiline text' field type. Now I have created a new column(say 'test') of type 'Sample' in a list. I created some list items.

I can edit the column value successfully from SharePoint UI (through edit form). But when I try to modify the value of 'test' column programatically for any list item, value of 'test' column for that list item becomes null/empty.

Any idea why this probem is occuring??  Below is the filedtypes xml that I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldTypes>
 <FieldType>
  <Field Name="TypeName">Sample</Field>
  <Field Name="ParentType">Note</Field>
  <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Sample</Field>
  <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Sample</Field>
  <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
  <Field Name="ShowInListCreate">TRUE</Field>
  <Field Name="ShowInSurveyCreate">TRUE</Field>
  <Field Name="ShowInDocumentLibraryCreate">TRUE</Field>
  <Field Name="ShowInColumnTemplateCreate">TRUE</Field>
  <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">
   SharePoint.Sample.FieldType, SharePoint.Sample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5560aa45b5518dc
  </Field>
  <Field Name="FieldEditorUserControl">
   /_controltemplates/FieldEditor.ascx
  </Field>
   <PropertySchema>
   <Fields>
    <Field Name="DisplayedListBoxProperty" DisplayName="DisplayedListBoxProperty"
     Type="Text" Hidden="True">
     <Default>"abc"</Default>
    </Field>
   </Fields>
  </PropertySchema>
 </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

Code that I am using to edit:

```
SPSite site = new  SPSite("site url")
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
SPListItem item  = list.Items[0];
item["test"] = "xyz";    //becomes null after update
item["numCol"] = "34";  //Gets updated to new value 34 after update
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
item.Update();
```

**One Important thing: This code runs in itemupdating eventhadler of another list.**

Comment: It seems their is some problem with your custom field type if you can share that code may be i can help you out

Comment: Share you code, are you using SharePointObjectModel or web Services?

Comment: Kindly browse to this location C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\WebServer Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\XML and Find your fldtypes_fieldname.xml file. And then validate if its correct

Comment: What is `item["test"]` before you update it?

Comment: @Kobi: If I try to get the value of item["test"], it gives me the correct value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I found the problem area. There is a function called GetValidatedString() which is used for any validation on the value. This function gets called even in case when you update value programmatically.
It was creating a problem.

Comment: 1 because this doesn't tell us how you solved the problem. What did you do to stop GetValidatedString() from being called? Or how did you work around that value being called?

Answer (score 1):

With your code, there is problem with your Custom Field Type with "FieldTypeClass". Try this 'SharePoint.Sample.FieldType, SharePoint.Sample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5560aa45b5518dc'

hope this will helps you.

Comment: hey Vivek : Actually that was a mistake of edit before posting. Actually I was using the same u suggested.

Comment: Anoop,try with web.allowunsafeupdates=true before list item updation.

Comment: thanx ...have already tried but no luck

Comment: Anoop, there is some problem with your Custom Field type, try to create another Custom Field Type with help of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415141.aspx